# Why can’t i run iOS project using KMM plugin on Windows?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I am absolutely new to [KMM](https://kotlinlang.org/lp/mobile/) (Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile) and I have never build cross-platform applications before. But I have experience with Android development and Kotlin. I wanted to give a try to KMM because I think that multiplatform applications will be getting more and more popular in the future.

I set up the environment needed for KMM project, I used [this tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/setup.html) for it. I updated to the latest version of Kotlin, installed KMM plugin in Android studio and got ready for the creating my first KMM project. Then I created a new project using [this tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/create-first-app.html#run-on-a-real-android-device) but I can't run my application on iOS because I can't see **iOS app** in the list of run configurations. I do not know how to resolve it. I have tried to restart, reinstall I have cleared my cache and tried to create another project but could not run iOS app.

I have built android applications before using Android studio and Kotlin and everything worked smooth.

Is there an error in KMM plugin?

Answer (score 5):

As you can see on their website [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-supported-platforms.html), in order to build an iOS app you need a macOS host. So the short answer is that you cannot build an iOS app using KMM on Windows.